# Optimizing a while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I've been working on HackerRank's list of algorithm problems. I keep getting a timeout error on this loop and was wondering if there was some way to speed it up? Some preliminary googling didn't turn up much.

Edit for context: The problem has two kangaroos, each of them have a starting position (k1, k2) and a movement speed (v1, v2). I have to determine if they will ever land on the same spot at the same time.

```
static String kangaroo(int k1, int v1, int k2, int v2) {
    int diff = Math.abs(k1 - k2);
    int newDiff = 0;
    String output = "";

   while (true){
        k1 += v1;
        k2 += v2;
        newDiff = Math.abs(k1 - k2);    
        if (k1 == k2){
            output = "YES";
            break;
        }
        else if (newDiff > diff){
            output = "NO";
            break;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: you don't even have to use a loop for this problem. :P

Comment: Unclear what the code is supposed to do, we don't know the problem from HackerRank

Comment: while(true) = asking for problems

Comment: If this is a problem about two kangaroos, with different starting positions and hop distances, then the problem is your solution is O(n), and no amount of clever tricks can reduce it's runtime below O(n). Try a different approach.

Comment: Unless this loop is running tens of millions of times, it should be lightning quick since it's just int comparisons.

Comment: for this particular problem (if i recalled this properly) you only need a single if condition as suggested by others in above comments for different approach

Comment: if `(x2-x1)/(v1-v2)` is a integer then yes they do meet,(some more conditions you have to check before it.. figure them out) and you should hacker-ranks discussion forum for this type of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty fast (`O(n)`), but this problem can be solved in constant time (`O(1)`), since it is just based on the condition of the intersection of two lines being an integer.

```
static String kangaroo(int k1, int v1, int k2, int v2) {
    float x = (k2 - k1)/(v1 - v2);
    if(x == (int) x) { //check if the intersection point is an integer
        return "YES";
    }
    return "NO";
}
```